# Anaconda "> was unexpected at this time"

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda

I downloaded Anaconda3 not too long ago and today when I tried to run the Anaconda Prompt program (Windows 64 bit system) it gave me the following output:

```
>was unexpected at this time
>IF DEFINED PYTHONIOENCODING chcp > NUL
```

Then it's only on the regular command line terminal.

It has not done this before today and I don't really know what is going on. I am new with anaconda and command line prompts in general.

I've found a few articles referring to the first line, but none that tell me anything about the second. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda. Painful and time-consuming, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by doing that as well but I have to do it every few days before it comes back again.

Answer (score 1):

I tried reinstalling anaconda, but to no avail. The same error kept recurring. It basically comes from line 40 in the file `conda.bat` located in `anaconda3\Library\bin\`

```
@IF DEFINED PYTHONIOENCODING chcp %PYTHONIOENCODING% > NUL
```

I tried modifying this line line in numerous ways, but nothing worked.

However, there is a small hack that did. Open command prompt (or even the Anaconda Prompt) `cd` into the directory `anaconda3\Scripts\`. The command `conda` works here. Typing `activate` should run the batch file and activate the default 'base' environment.

Alternatively, just type `anaconda3\Scripts\activate`. Just do this each time you want to run the Anaconda Prompt, and you should be good to go.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfTd2.png)